# Change property of object in another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITabBarController` (as initial view controller) which checks connectivity status of the device. Everytime the connectivity status changes, a checkmark in a child UITableViewController cell (`.accessoryType`) should be set (`.checkmark`) or removed (`.none`)

Code in Tab Bar Controller:

```
let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
    let tvc = InfoTableViewController()
    if path.status == .satisfied {
        // set .checkmark in UITableViewController
        let cell = tvc.statusOnlineCell
        print("cell :", cell)
    } else {
        // set .none in UITableViewController
    }
}
let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
monitor.start(queue: queue)
```

Outlet in `UITableViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var statusOnlineCell: UITableViewCell!
```

I can change the accessory type from inside the `UITableViewController` class using `.checkmark` and `.none`.

```
statusOnlineCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
statusOnlineCell.accessoryType = .none
```

All fine so far!

However as soon as I try to access the `UITableView.statusOnlineCell` from `UITabBar`, I get `nil`. Hence, I cannot change its property outside the `UITableViewController`.

I saw 3 possible approaches:

1. A global variable, which reflects the online status. I could use the `UITableView.viewDidAppear()` method to change the `statusOnlineCell` accessory type. This works, but only if `UITableView` is not shown (only if another than `UITableView` is shown). If the `UITableView` is shown and I change the connectivity status, the view is not reloaded and I didn't find any way to achieve this. Is this possible?
2. Find a possibility to change the accessory type of `UITableView.statusOnlineCell` from the `UITabBarController`. Accessing the outlook returned in nil.  Why is that? On top, after the accessory type would have changed, I would need to reload the view (for the case that the `UITableView` was active while changing connectivity status).
3. Is there any kind of (unknown to me) method which fires, when an object's property changed (à la `needReload()`)? This would be too good to be true I believe.

To summarize - I need code to change the accessory type of a tableview cell, depending on the connectivity status, even whith this tableview being visible.

I read some tutorials and stackexchange articles, Google, ... but none did the job.

This was my top candidate, but I didn't manager to apply these examples to my situation.
https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/#back-delegation

I didn't want to use notifications since not really appropriate.

Any hint would be sufficient. Thanks in advance.

**----- EDIT (14:52 UTC) -----** (requested by @vadian)

I added the (testing) code in the `UITabBarController`. The result of `cell` shows `nil`. So I cannot directly address the cell in `UITableView` from `UITabBarController`.

The `UITableView` doesn't have any related code yet since I directly address the property `statusOnlineCell` from `UITabBarController` in order to change its accessory type.

This approach is option 2. (of my 3 possibilities mentioned above).

Comment: You need the reference to the table view controller instance in the tab bar controller. Please add the relevant code how both controllers are related.

Comment: Edit done. The adds are for option 2. Please check if option 1. Could be this an easier approach.Thanks.

Comment: Do not edit the question to give an answer. If you’ve solved it, post the solution as an answer. Answering your own question is fine.

Comment: I thought about that, but strictly speaking, my solution is no answer to my question, hence the edit. Ok ... I'll make out of my workaround an answer. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution, but a workaround.

Why no solution : the `cell` object was always `nil` if called from another class. Hence no chance to change it's property to `.checkmark` or `.none`. This was basically my key problem and unknown to me.

The workaround : a delegate! I declared the class, holding the cell, as delegate for the connectivity status change. Like that, the checkmark gets set or is removed from the cell, independantly whether the page is in view or not.

This runs when the app starts (`UITabBarController`):

```
protocol StatusOnlineChangedDelegate {
    func updateStatusOnline(_ online: Bool)
}

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    var socDelegate: StatusOnlineChangedDelegate?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            if path.status == .satisfied {
                self.socDelegate?.updateStatusOnline(true)
            } else {
                self.socDelegate?.updateStatusOnline(false)

            }
        }
        let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
}
```

The `UITableViewController` holding the cell looks like this:

```
class InfoTableViewController: UITableViewController, StatusOnlineChangedDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var statusOnlineCell: UITableViewCell!       
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TabBarController().socDelegate = self
    }
    func updateStatusOnline(_ online: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.statusOnlineCell.accessoryType = (online ? .checkmark : .none)
        }
    }   
}
```

Runs perfectly as desired.